# Сортировка по алфавиту. Помогите

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, textarea, replace

Суть задачи такова что в textarea вводятся ссылки, а функция должна вырезать из  них "https://" и вернуть отсортированный список ссылок. Удалить "https://" я смог, а вот как отсортировать не могу придумать. Метод sort() пытался применить, объявляя text_area как new Array но у меня ничего не получилось. Новичок просит помощи.

```js
function textArea(form) {
  var text_area = form.text.value;

  console.log(text_area.replace(/https:\u002F\u002F/g, ""));

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="text"></textarea>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" onclick="textArea(form)"></p>
  </form>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var preData = [
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript',
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/массивы',
  '           ',
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/сортировка',
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textarea',
  'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace',
  '           '
];

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = preData.join('\n');
}

function textArea(form) {
  var processed = form.text.value.split('\n').map(function(item) {
    return item.trim().replace(/^http(s):\/\//, '');
  }).filter(function(item) {
    return item;
  }).sort().join('\n');
  form.text.value = processed;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea rows="8" cols="60" id="text"></textarea>
  <p><input type="button" value="Подготовить" onclick="textArea(form)"></p>
</form>
```